# Lateinit property viewModel has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, mvvm, android-viewmodel

I initialized `viewModel` with this line `viewModel = (activity as NewsActivity).viewModel` in `BreakingNewsFragment` but, recived below error.
How i can fix this problem?! thanks for your help

**BreakingNewsFragment**

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.View
import com.example.simplenewsapp.R
import com.example.simplenewsapp.main.MainViewModel
import com.example.simplenewsapp.NewsActivity
import com.example.simplenewsapp.adapter.NewsRecyclerViewAdapter
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_breaking_news.*


class BreakingNewsFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_breaking_news) {

    lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        viewModel = (activity as NewsActivity).viewModel


         ....
```

**NewsActivity**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.example.simplenewsapp.data.local.ArticleDatabase
import com.example.simplenewsapp.main.MainRepository
import com.example.simplenewsapp.main.MainViewModel
import com.example.simplenewsapp.main.MainViewModelProviderFactory
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_news.*

class NewsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news)

        val newsRepository = MainRepository(ArticleDatabase(this))
        val mainViewModelProviderFactory = MainViewModelProviderFactory(newsRepository)
        viewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this, mainViewModelProviderFactory).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
        
        bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(newsNavHostFragment.findNavController())
    }
}
```

**MainViewModelProviderFactory**

```
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider

class MainViewModelProviderFactory(val mainRepository:MainRepository): ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return MainViewModel(mainRepository) as T
    }
}
```

**MainViewModel**

```
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.example.simplenewsapp.data.local.models.NewsResponse
import com.example.simplenewsapp.util.Resource
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import retrofit2.Response

class MainViewModel(
    val newsRepository: MainRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    val breakingNews: MutableLiveData<Resource<NewsResponse>> = MutableLiveData()
    var breakingNewsPage = 1

    init {
        getBreakingNews("us")
    }

    fun getBreakingNews(countyCode: String) = viewModelScope.launch {
        breakingNews.postValue(Resource.Loading())

        val response = newsRepository.getBreakingNews(countyCode, breakingNewsPage)

        breakingNews.postValue(handleBreakingNewsResponse(response))
    }

    private fun handleBreakingNewsResponse(response: Response<NewsResponse>): Resource<NewsResponse> {
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            response.body()?.let { resultResponse ->
                return Resource.Success(resultResponse)
            }
        }
        return Resource.Error(response.message())
    }


}
```

**Error:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.simplenewsapp, PID: 4455
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.simplenewsapp/com.example.simplenewsapp.NewsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property viewModel has not been initialized
        at com.example.simplenewsapp.NewsActivity.getViewModel(NewsActivity.kt:16)
        at com.example.simplenewsapp.ui.fragments.BreakingNewsFragment.onViewCreated(BreakingNewsFragment.kt:29)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2974)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:543)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1636)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3112)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:3049)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2975)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.ensureInflatedView(FragmentStateManager.java:389)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:281)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:141)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:313)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:292)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.example.simplenewsapp.NewsActivity.onCreate(NewsActivity.kt:20)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4455 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Firstly why you are using same `View Model` for fragment and activity ?
   This approach is incorrect and may lead to inconsistent data and memory leaks.
   Ideally fragment and activity should have their own independent `View Model`.
   For example:
   a) NewsActivity and NewsViewModel
   b) BreakingNewsFragment and BreakingNewsViewModel
2. This separates the code by following the `Separation of concerns` principle and you will get benefit from this as your application logic grows.
   And If you are looking for shared behavior/data, please used `Shared View Model`.
3. Secondly, instead of using the `View Model` from `NewsActivity`
   you should initialize it completely in `BreakingNewsFragment`, the way you did in `NewsActivity`.

```
// Add below code either in your fragment or activity.

 val newsRepository = MainRepository(ArticleDatabase(this))
 val mainViewModelProviderFactory = MainViewModelProviderFactory(newsRepository)
 viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, mainViewModelProviderFactory).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
```

Answer (score 4):

I know it's late but I'm happy to find the solution:

The problem was fragment tag of xml.

I changed the fragment tag to androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView.

and initializing the fragmentcontentview and setting up nav controller:

```kotlin
val navHostFragment= supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.newsNavHostFrag) as NavHostFragment
val navController= navHostFragment.navController
bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

Comment: for those still having error following Philip Lackner's code,
https://github.com/sijan8s3/MVVM-News-App/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/sijanneupane/mvvmnews/ui/MainActivity.kt
here's the NewsActivity file,
and the xml, 
https://github.com/sijan8s3/MVVM-News-App/blob/main/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml

Answer (score 1):

Use this dependency instead:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
```

and use this version only.
I used to use `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'`, and that creates the same error as you are facing.

Try once and use `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'` dependency and exact the same version - that's what worked for me.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Downgrading the version solves the problem. Though it changes the colors in the navigation menu. Can you explain why it works?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using fragment like this:-

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/flFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/newsNavHostFragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/news_nav_graph" />

</FrameLayout>
```

then you have to change your appcompat dependency version 1.3.1 to 1.2.0 like this

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
```

but if you are using latest dependency version i.e 1.3.1 then you have to use

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/newsNavHostFrag"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/news_nav_graph"/>
```

and in MainActivity.kt
change this :-

```
bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(newsNavHostFragment.findNavController())
```

to this:-

```
val navHostFragment= supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.newsNavHostFrag) as NavHostFragment
    val navController= navHostFragment.navController
    bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below line instead of lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

```
private val viewModel:MainViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

Also , if you can't import it check for this dependency in app level build.gradle

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.1.0'
```

and remove this line : viewModel = (activity as NewsActivity).viewModel

Answer (score 0):

For solving this error, you have to put this code in your activity as well as in your fragment both

in Newsactivity:-

```
val newsResporiaty = NewsResporiaty(ArticleDatabase(requireContext()))
val viewModelFactory = NewsViewModelProviderFactory(newsResporiaty)
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this,viewModelFactory).get(NewsViewModel::class.java)
```

And also your in fragmets:-

```
val newsResporiaty = NewsResporiaty(ArticleDatabase(requireContext()))
val viewModelFactory = NewsViewModelProviderFactory(newsResporiaty)
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this,viewModelFactory).get(NewsViewModel::class.java)
```

This worked for me.